# Random initialization of local variable C++

Tags: c++17

While creating and running a small piece of code to see how global and local variables are initialized,the global array outputs a zero(because global variables are initialzed with zero).

But why is it that the printed values of the local array change randomly everytime you re-build the program?

```cpp
 #include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int global[1];

int main()
{
    int local[1];
    cout<<"global is:"<<global[0]<<global[1]<<"\n";
    cout<<"local is:"<<local[0]<<local[1]<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int global[1];
int main()
{

int local[1];
cout<<"global is:"<<global[0]<<" "<<global[1]<<"\n";
cout<<"local is:"<<local[0]<<" "<<local[1]<<"\n";

  return 0;
}

Comment: im sorry for this,as I was posting the question,the global[1] of the program was invisible.

Comment: int local[1]{};  //< this will initialise to zero

Comment: Also, don't access global[1] or local[1] when printing. The last accessible elements are global[0] and local[0].

Answer (score 0):

Global variables behave like static in C++ (behaviour defined by standard). Their values are set to 0. They also have a special place in memory.

Local variables, on the other hand, if left unitialized have their values undefined. Which means when you run the program it just reads the data there are at the memory where the structure is allocated. Those are the seemingly random values you encounter.